# Django Rest Framework fails to handle malformed JSON

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have the following function in Django Rest Framework:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT'])
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
def TestView(request, app_id):
  return Response({})
```

It should always return a json response with the empty object, right? Wrong. If I `PUT` data at this url with media type `application/json`, and send it *malformed json*, then Django barfs out a 500 response:

```
ParseError at /api/v1/test-url
No exception message supplied
```

I feel like DRF should either raise an exception that I can catch, or send out a 400 error. In fact, the docs even state:

> The wrappers also provide behaviour such as returning 405 Method Not
>   Allowed responses when appropriate, and handling any ParseError
>   exception that occurs when accessing request.DATA with malformed
>   input.

So why is my application spitting out a 500 error?

Comment: Have you tried with a class based view?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a [custom exception handler](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions#custom-exception-handling) and handle the ParseError in there.

Comment: That *would* fix it - but I feel like you shouldn't need to implement a custom exception handler just to handle bad json data.

Comment: Well, alternatively you can implement your own JSONParser class and configure it to be the default JSONParser. However, since what you're trying to do is to handle an exceptional case(invalid json) in a different way, I would have preferred a custom exception handler.